# IOException in android app with system privileges

Tags: android, android-manifest, ioexception, android-external-storage

I am trying to write/read from an SD card using the following code:

```
     try {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,INITIAL_FILE_NAME);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
     }
    catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
    }
```

In the manifest I'm giving the following permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

However when trying to read, I'm getting the following exception:

```
     open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I'm giving my app system privileges (for other needed tasks) with

```
     android:sharedUserId = "android.uid.system"
```

When I removed the privilege, I can access the sdcard. For some reason the system privileges are in conflict with reading/writing from the sdcard.

Can someone tell me the reason behind this? Is there a way to manage both?

Comment: Which permission did you set?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda sorry my bad, I edited the question

Comment: add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: MANAGE_DOCUMENTS  permission if you are using KIT_KAT...

Comment: @PradeepYaduvanshy I've tried that, and I'm not using KIT_KAT. It appears that it's not possible to do both..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes that continue holding open folders on the SD Card a little after it is requested to be unmounted will be killed so that it can unmount.

We don't want the system process to  be able to access the SD Card to avoid these kinds of issues (and just general security cleanliness), so that it does not have permission to access it.

If you want to access the SD card, you should not use the system shared user ID.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would it work if I access the SD card from a background service? Or Am I bound to the same problem?

Comment: @user1851212 Your problem will persist even after that as far as I'm aware but you can give it a shot and mark this as answer if you got what you needed.

Comment: didn't work out. However there's a solution, I'm not sure if it's good approach but I'm doing the following:
Create another application with only a service inside it. I do the sdcard read/write processes there. I can call that service from my application. What do you think? (bare in mind, the application am doing is not commercial, so it's flexible from that perspective)